# BLOB Download Truncated at 1 MB Script Works for Files Less Than 1 MB

Tags: php, mysql, blob

I just recently asked and solved a question pertaining to uploading .PDF files that are greater than 2 MB into a MySQL database as BLOBS. I had to change some settings in my php.ini file and MySQLs maximum packet setting.  However, fixing this issue has led me to discover a new issue with my script.

Now since I can upload files to my BLOB database I attempted to download the file for testing purposes. Much to my dismay when I went to open the .PDF file I received the following error:  Failed to load document (error 3) 'file:///tmp/test-13.pdf'.  Upon further investigation I found out that the file being downloaded, test.pdf, was only 1 MB, a little less than half of its supposed size in the database of a little more than 2 MB.  This is obviously the reason for the error.

The following piece of code is the part of my script I am using for downloading files from the database.  It is is at the very top of of script and  **works Flawlessly for files that are less than 1 MB.**

```
 foreach($_REQUEST as $key => $value)
 {
 if ($value == 'Open')
   {
    header();
    session_start();
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.$_SESSION['OpsDBServer'].'.ops.tns.its.psu.edu;  
           dbname='.$_SESSION['OpsDB'], $_SESSION['yoM'], $_SESSION['aMa']);
    $id = $key;
    $sqlDownload = "SELECT name, type, content, size  FROM upload WHERE 
    id='".$id."'";
    $result = $dbh->query($sqlDownload);

    $download = $result->fetchAll();
    $type = $download[0]['type'];
    $size = $download[0]['size'];
    $name = $download[0]['name'];
    $content = $download[0]['content'];

    header("Content-type: $type");
    header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=$name");
    header("Content-length: $size");
    header("Cache-Control: maxage=1");
    header("Pragma: public");

    echo $content;

    exit;
   }
 }
```

I am thinking that maybe I have some header statements wrong?  I am very confused about what to do.  I have searched through php.ini and I have found no settings that I think need to changed and my maximum packet setting for MySQL is 4 MB so a 2 MB should download.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you double-check that *size* is set correctly in your database?

Comment: I have not checked, but I will when I get back to work Monday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually fixed the issue.  I changed all of the values that were recommended here in php.ini and my.cnf but I also needed to change a setting for PDO.

I changed:
PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE (integer)
Maximum buffer size. Defaults to 1 MiB.

This has to be set when the PDO object is created to work though.  All is good now.

Answer (score 2):

According to (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html):

> The maximum size of
>   a BLOB or TEXT object is determined by
>   its type, but the largest value you
>   actually can transmit between the
>   client and server is determined by the
>   amount of available memory and the
>   size of the communications buffers.
>   You can change the message buffer size
>   by changing the value of the
>   max_allowed_packet variable, but you
>   must do so **for both the server and
>   your client** program.

According to (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-parameters.html) the default value for max_allowed_packet is 1048576.

Comment: I have already had the database administrator change the value of max_allowed_packet on the server side to 4MB.  Is there something I need to change on the client side as well?